# How to replace the links inside of a file by sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file named 1.txt and it contains below 3 URLs, each of them following a http link, which I want to change them using sed command. The link could be regard as a string without space.

```
  URL1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw5ZK.png
  URL2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT8Pv.png
  URL3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Syn.png
```

My purpose is to use something like below to replce those 3 links from command line, like:

```
sed **** 1.txt https://abc/1.png https://abc/2.png https://abc/3.png
```

After the command executes, the new content of 1.txt would be:

```
  URL1: https://abc/1.png
  URL2: https://abc/2.png
  URL3: https://abc/3.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ awk '{a=gensub(/URL([^:]+):/,"\\1",1,$1);sub(/i\.stack\.imgur.com\/.*/,"abc",$2);print $1,$2"/"a".png"}' 1.txt
URL1: https://abc/1.png
URL2: https://abc/2.png
URL3: https://abc/3.png
```

`a=gensub(/URL([^:]+):/,"\\1",1,$1)` captures the numeric part of the URL in the first column.
`sub(/i\.stack\.imgur.com\/.*/,"abc",$2)` replaces the entire actual url with `https://abc` in the second column.

`print $1,$2"/"a".png"` prints the new line with the new, numbered png.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple wrapper which changes your command line parameters into a proper `sed` script. We are simply indexing by line number.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
shift

script=()  # empty array
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    script+=(-e "${i}s|http.*|${!i}|")
done
sed "${script[@]}" "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~(URL([0-9]):[^:]*://).*~\1abc/\2.png~' input_file
URL1: https://abc/1.png
URL2: https://abc/2.png
URL3: https://abc/3.png
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do with `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="//"} {$2 = "abc/" ++n ".png"} 1' file

  URL1: https://abc/1.png
  URL2: https://abc/2.png
  URL3: https://abc/3.png
```

Alternative `awk` solution using `sub`:

```bash
awk '{sub(/\/\/.+/, "//abc/" ++n ".png")} 1' file

  URL1: https://abc/1.png
  URL2: https://abc/2.png
  URL3: https://abc/3.png
```